# GCC leaking its lambda implementation into the user's program?

Tags: c++11, gcc, lambda, compiler-bug

How is it possible that the following code is successfully compiled by GCC version [6..10] ?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto const answer = 42;
    auto lambda = [&answer] {};
    auto *p = &(lambda.__answer);

    return p != &answer; // return 0 (success) if they are the same
}
```

Is GCC leaking its internal representation of lambdas into the user's program?

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xTWxso)

Answer (score 4):

> **[lex.name]**
> (3) In addition, some identifiers are reserved for use by C++ implementations and **shall not** be used otherwise; **no diagnostic is required**.
> (3.1) Each identifier that contains a double underscore `__` or begins with an underscore followed by an
> uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use.

> **[intro]**
> If a program contains a violation of a rule for which no diagnostic is required, this document places **no requirement** on implementations with respect to that program.

> **[defns.undefined]**
> **undefined behavior**: behavior for which this document imposes no requirements.

Thus the program behaviour is undefined.

Comment: +1 I think that's pretty much it. You might want to explain that the original code triggers UB, maybe the OP didn't understand it.

Comment: Are you saying that the standard allows GCC to accept this code?

Comment: @Bulletmagnet The standard says "no diagnostic is required" and I can add nothing to it.

Comment: Invoking [lex.name](3) here doesn't sound right; that would make any program that uses e.g. `__builtin_alloca()` ill-fromed (NDR).

Comment: @Bulletmagnet A program that uses e.g. `__builtin_alloca()` has UB as far as the standard is concerned. Implementations are allowed to have documented extensions though. If `__builtin_alloca()` is documented by some implementation, it is OK to use it with that implementation. The standard does not make guarantees w.r.t. such a program, the implementation does.